# How to terminate/exit/abort old thread workers and restart program?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have these control buttons (Windows.Forms):

`Start/Restart` | `Pause` | `Continue`

Once `Start` is pressed, `threadPool[workerThreadsCount]` is created, `ManualResetEvent mre` is set to `mre.Set()` and threads start doing their job. In some pseudo-code:

```
threadStartingPoint() {
int index = 0;
while(index !== someMaxCondition)
      ... // grab some data to work on
      lock(_lock) {  // lock index, so one access at a time
        index += index;
      }
      ... // do some stuff
      _mre.WaitOne(); // Pause if button Pause is pressed.
    }
}
```

Worker threads work in a loop like in example above. Now if I press `pause`, everything stop at `_mre.Wait();` position. With `continue` I can open gates using `mre.Set()` and everything works just fine. Now the problem is when I `Pause`, I want user to choose between `Continue` or `Restart`. The problem with `Restart` is that I have no idea how to tell my threads to exit that `while loop`. Because If I just set `mre.Set()` and create new threads, for some time the old ones will still work with that old data loop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to use the overload of `WaitOne` that takes a timeout value. Then in the while test conditional, test for some pause or quit condition.

Comment: fyi `index` is local to the thread, you don't need to lock on it because only one thread can ever touch it.

Answer (score 2):

Pass in a [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) and have it checked each loop.

```
private volatile CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

threadStartingPoint() {
int index = 0;
var token = _tokenSource.Token;
while(index !== someMaxCondition && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
      ... // grab some data to work on
      lock(_lock) {  // lock index, so one access at a time
        index += index;
      }
      ... // do some stuff
      _mre.WaitOne(); // Pause if button Pause is pressed.
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the Cancel button have it send a Cancel to the [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) the tokens are derived from. Then new workers can just use a new Token Source that are unaffected by the previous cancelation.

```
private void ButtonCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get a local copy of the source and replace the global copy
    var tokenSource = _tokenSource;
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    //Cancel all loops that used the old token source
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    mre.Set();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "by the book" answer is to consider implementing a [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

But, if you already have working code, I would just add a variable `bool restartRequested=false;`.

When the user then requests a restart, set `restartRequested=true;` and reset the `_mre`.  Then break the while loop and let the thread method complete, if `restartRequested==true`.

Comment: Use of simple variables is not recommended in Multithreading due to volatility when accessing the data. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/printable.shtml

Comment: @DonJayamanne , Normally I would agree with you.  But, this code is already stopped on a WaitHandle.  Volatility is not an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another ManualResetEvent that gets set only when the "Restart" button is clicked.
Here's the updated code using the new WaitHandle.

```
threadStartingPoint() {
int index = 0;
//We have two waithandles that we need to wait on
var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[] {_mre, _restartMre};
while(index !== someMaxCondition)
      ... // grab some data to work on
      lock(_lock) {  // lock index, so one access at a time
        index += index;
      }
      ... // do some stuff

      //Wait on any one of the wait handles to signal
      WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles);
      if (_restartMre.WaitOne(0)){
          break;
      }
    }
}
```